# UISplitViewController for iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape

I want to create an iPhone (not iPad) app with a split screen view that shows two view controllers on the same screen, one on the left and one on the right of the screen (landscape only).

Is there a way to make UISplitViewController work for iPhone, or is there an open source library i can use to achieve this look?

Comment: UISplitViewController is iPad only

Comment: Isn't the iPhone screen too small for the split view. That is one of the main reasons Apple have made it an iPad-Specific ViewController.

Comment: The landscape view has enough space for my purposes, I think apple should have allowed UISplitViewController on iPhone also. Do you know any open source library that mimics this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

As said, you can not use a split view controller.  However, I dont think you need it anyway.  Its a little cumbersome and restrictive.

You can achieve the effect of the split view controller easily using subviews.  (Try to avoid using multiple view controllers as this is generally bad practice).

Create two custom views and ad them as sub views to the main view.  Look at their auto resizing properties.  Try to use interface builder.  Show / hide you side view when the user rotates.

UISplitViewControllers aren't that useful - you can mimic their effectes easily.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can achieve this using the `UISplitViewController` class. If you take a look at the [Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW4) documents it clearly states that the `UISplitViewController` is an iPad-specific viewcontroller.

Note this point

> If you are developing a universal application, though, be sure not to create and use these controllers when your application is running on an iPhone or iPod touch.

Comment: This is no longer the case in 2019