# How to achieve custom calendar in ipad app which looks like outlook calendar and has events(can be multiple events at the same duration) for the day

Tags: ipad, calendar

I am developing an iPad application in which data of calendar events for the day comes from the webservice and i have to display the data in a calendar UI which looks like outlook calendar. Multiple evens can be there for a specific time for that day. So that multiple columns should be there in the events side. Please help me how can I get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use and try out by having multiple UITableviews in one single nib file. May be you can use two table views for each day/time as per your requirement

Here's are links which i found -  [iphone app with two UITableViewControllers side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888310/iphone-app-with-two-uitableviewcontrollers-side-by-side)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/50502-creating-view-two-table-views.html

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you a bit for creating UI and Event arrangements.

https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui

Please update the Graphics and Color Schemes according to your requirement.

Enjoy Coding :)